# Как ввести обратный слэш в Python?

Tags: python

Суть в том, что хочу присвоить имя переменной:

```
name = ('folder\' + pName + '.txt')
```

Но место этого получаю оранжевый символ. Че делать то?

Comment: После folder, идет знак '\'

Comment: Опечатка вышла.

Comment: Не знаю правильно срабоатет но попробуйте так: name = ('folder\'pName\'.txt')

Answer (score 1):

Экранировать:

```
name = ('folder\\' + pName + '.txt')
```

Comment: Спасибо, в долгу не останусь

Comment: Во втором варианте слеш все равно будет экранировать кавычку, будет ошибка синтаксиса

Comment: @insolor ну да, странно, думал с кавычками тоже работает.

Comment: Ну, такая вот особенность, в конце строки в любом случае нужно экранировать.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно собирать путь своими руками.

```
from os import path

name = path.join('folder', f'{pName}.txt')
```